# Using Guzzle with Cloudflare images service

Tags: php, image, cloudflare, guzzle

I'm using the cloudflare image service but I can not find an working example using guzzle.

I want to upload an image using direct upload and custom id:

```
curl --request POST https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/<account-id>/images/v1
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>'
  --form 'file=@/path/to/image/c1.jpg'
  --form 'id=test_123456'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

use \GuzzleHttp\Client;

/**
 * Class cloudFlareUpload
 */
class Upload
{
    /**
     * CloudFlare account id
     * @var string
     */
    private $account_id = '<account-id>';

    /**
     * CloudFlare images service token
     * @var string
     */
    private $image_token_id = '<token>';


    public function directFileUpload($custom_id, $path){

        try{
            $url = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/{$this->account_id}/images/v1";
            $client = new Client(['timeout' => 10.0]);
            $options = [
                "headers" => [
                    "Authorization" => "Bearer {$this->image_token_id}"
                ],
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'file',
                        'contents' => fopen($path, 'r')
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'id',
                        'contents' => $custom_id
                    ]
                ],
            ];
            return $client->request('POST', $url, $options)->getBody()->getContents();

        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            // do something here
        }

    }
}
```